# Which jQuery selection is more efficient?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Which set of selectors is more efficient?

## 1

```
$('#parent_element span.class1').do_something1();
$('#parent_element span.class2').do_something2();
$('#parent_element span.class3').do_something3();
$('#parent_element span.class4').do_something4();
```

## 2

```
$parent_element = $('#parent_element'); 
$parent_element.find('span.class1').do_something1();
$parent_element.find('span.class2').do_something2();
$parent_element.find('span.class3').do_something3();
$parent_element.find('span.class4').do_something4();
```

My guess is #2 is more effecient as it begins a search `find()` focused on the parent element vs the entire DOM. Is this true?

If so how many calls to that parent element would be needed to make it more efficient than #1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution #2 is wildly more efficient. Caching selectors in jQuery is one of the best ways to cut down on the time it takes to do selections. For any uses greater than 1, go with solution 2.

Answer (score 5):

As with anything like this, you MUST test with a tool like jsperf if you want the real answer.  The test shows that the second is much faster than the first.

**If** they were all the same method calls or you could process each one in a `.each(fn)` method, you could combine them all like this and the selector operation would be significantly faster:

```
$('#parent_element').find('span.class1, span.class2, span.class3, span.class4').each(fn);
```

[image]

You can run it yourself here: http://jsperf.com/selector-options.  Your first option is the orange.  Your second option is the blue.  The combined selector is the red.  The cached parent is about 30-80% faster.  If they can all be combined into one selector, it's multiple times faster.

Comment: @iambriansreed - please see my latest version of the answer with the performance test which is the real data.

Comment: @iambriansreed. And why is that?! it looks fine for me. **+1**

Comment: @gdoron jfriend00's `or` example obviously isn't pertinent as each element is doing something different in my question. A grouped selector is nice and all but not relevant to the question.

Comment: @iambriansreed - excuse me for actually running the performance tests that everyone else offered conjecture about.  This is the only answer that has actual performance numbers which is how all performance questions that matter should be answered.

Comment: @iambriansreed - As for the grouped selector, I included it because in the cases where a single function can be used to process multiple elements (even if that function has to do some part of it's work differently for each item), it is a LOT faster.  You haven't disclosed what your real operation is so we can't say for sure whether that would be a possibility for you, but many times it is.  Maybe not something you want to consider, but it is relevant to the community who might read this so I thought it was useful to add.  Apparently, I've been downvoted for adding extra info about that.